# What is the Seagate GO Flex External HDD standard and how does it differ from USB?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I am looking at the specs for seagate 1 TB 2.5" external hdds. I see there are two variants of external hdd. One says *USB expansion* another is *Go Flex*. What are the technical differences between these two interfaces?

Comment: Provide links to both.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it look less like a buying recommendation. I have to say that the Seagate site covers Go Flex in full detail and a simple Web search will bring up all the info you need - eg: http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/external/external-hard-drive/portable-hard-drive In essence, Go Flex provides a generic device interface that can be used with USB 2, USB 3, firewire or eSATA adaptors as your interface needs change or faster standards emerge.

Comment: Should have been an answer, Linker3000.

Comment: You never know what kind of disk you are getting when you buy goflex or expansion external drives. Seagate will put whatever disks they have available at the time in whatever cases they have. There is no consistency. This is why Seagate never specifices transfer mode, buffer size or rotation speed. If you're lucky you'll get SATA/600, 32MB, and 7200RPM... if not, will be SATA/300, unknown, 5900RMP. They only say, obviously, connection type and size. I just bought a 3TB expansion disk which is a good one (made in Thailand) I also just bought a 2TB expansion which is a bad one - in fact, it thin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GoFlex has a removable base, which is the interface. Typically, most people would buy it with the new USB3 option, but you can buy it with USB2 or other interfaces. If you don't need to run the hard drive on computers with varying interfaces, you can just buy a unit with a dedicated USB interface, but I would buy one with USB3 at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the rather [content-free](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/content-free) explanations on Seagates [webpage](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/external/external-hard-drive/) regarding GoFlex I get the idea that all GoFlex entails is an interface and a set of cables and adaptors to allow a hard drive to be used on *any* type of computer, be it a PC, Mac, tablet or even iPad (via wireless).  It seems to imply that it also allows upgrade to future standards such as USB3 somehow.

If you know that all the computers you are connecting to have no special connection needs, for example you're only ever going to connect it to machines that have USB2, then GoFlex will be of little benefit and the cheaper drive will likely suit your needs just fine.

If you require connecting the drive to all sorts of weird and wonderful hardware then GoFlex may be what you are looking for, but I suspect you'll end up buying new adaptors for each new thing you want to plug it in to.